# Inter Thread Communication Even Odd Example

Tags: java, multithreading

I have implemented a simple example for inter thread communication which have 2 threads to print even and odd numbers in sequence.

I am looking for a feedback and points for improving the example.

My code looks like:

```
public class InterThreadCommunicationEvenOddExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        NumberResource numberResource = new NumberResource();
        new EvenThread(numberResource);
        new OddThread(numberResource);
    }
}


class EvenThread implements Runnable
{

    NumberResource numberResource;



    EvenThread(final NumberResource numberResource)
    {
        this.numberResource = numberResource;
        new Thread(this, "Even").start();
    }



    public void run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            System.out.println("Even Thread::" + this.numberResource.getNextEven());
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {

            }
        }
    }

}


class OddThread implements Runnable
{

    NumberResource numberResource;



    OddThread(final NumberResource numberResource)
    {
        this.numberResource = numberResource;
        new Thread(this, "Odd").start();
    }



    public void run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            System.out.println("Odd Thread::" + this.numberResource.getNextOdd());
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}


class NumberResource
{

    private int number = 0;



    public synchronized int getNextEven()
    {
        while (isEven(number))
        {
            try
            {
                wait();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {

            }

        }
        number++;
        notify();
        return number;
    }



    public synchronized int getNextOdd()
    {
        while (!isEven(number))
        {
            try
            {
                wait();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {

            }

        }
        number++;
        notify();
        return number;
    }



    private boolean isEven(int number)
    {
        return number % 2 == 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is some refactoring that could be made.

### Naming

`EvenThread` and `OddThread` aren't really threads since they don't implement the [`Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) class. There are two options:

1. Rename the two classes to something more appropriate/fitting with its purpose

   - e.g., `EvenRunner`/`OddRunner`
2. Move the thread management to the `InterThreadCommunicationEvenOddExample.main` method. This is more standard.

### Redundancy

- `OddThread` and `EvenThread` have almost the same functionality; a `NumberThread` could be created that paramaterizes the parity (e.g., a `Parity` enum parameter). This would be ideal since the logic in `run()` would only need to be changed **once** if needed.
- The above point could be applied to `getNextOdd` and `getNextEven` in a similar manner.

### Modifiers

Some variables could use tighter modifiers to better convey their purpose.

- `NumberResource numberResource` could be `final` in all of its occurrences.
- `private boolean isEven(int number)` could be made `static` since it is constant with respect to each `NumberResource` instance; furthermore, a semantic argument *could* be made that `isEven(number)` is not asking whether the `NumberResource` instance is even but rather asking if the provided `number` is even.

### Threads

- There is no need to call `Thread.sleep()` inside `EvenThread.run()` or `OddThread.run()`, since there is a `wait()` and `notify()` statement in the `NumberResource`'s block. A single thread at a time will "wake up" from the `wait()` call after `notify()` is called in another thread, so removing the `Thread.sleep()` calls won't burn CPU cycles.
- If the `Thread.sleep()` call is there for the sole purpose of text not flashing quickly onto the screen, then that is fine. Though moving the `Thread.sleep()` into the `NumberResource` method(s), before the `notify()` call, would cause text to be printed more evenly.

### Empty `catch` statements

- Either log something here or write a comment explaining why no action is taken here.
- Allowing `getNextOdd`/`getNextEven` to throw an `InterruptedException` exception might even be cleaner.
- A javadoc string for each method/class could clarify this as well.

### Spacing

Overall, the spacing is fine and consistent, but `3` empty lines between each class method seems like too much, but this is subjective.

---

It is interesting to note that the overall output order of the messages is **not** guaranteed since `notify()` is called inside of `getNextOdd`/`getNextEven`; however, it is guaranteed that each `Even Thread::{num}` message will be strictly increasing (by `2`). The same goes for each `Odd Thread::{num}` message.
Below is an example of some of the refactoring comments made above (except adding `Javadocs`).

```
public class InterThreadCommunicationEvenOddExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final NumberResource numberResource = new NumberResource();
        final Thread[] numberThreads = new Thread[] {
            new Thread(new NumberRunner(numberResource, Parity.EVEN)),
            new Thread(new NumberRunner(numberResource, Parity.ODD)),
        };

        for (Thread numberThread : numberThreads) {
            numberThread.start();
        }

        for (Thread numberThread : numberThreads) {
            numberThread.join();
        }
    }
}

class NumberResource {
    private int number = 0;

    public synchronized int getNextNumber(Parity parity) throws InterruptedException {
        while (getParity(number) != parity) {
            wait();
        }
        final int nextNumber = number++;
        notify();
        return nextNumber;
    }

    private static Parity getParity(final int number) {
        return number % 2 == 0 ? Parity.EVEN : Parity.ODD;
    }
}

class NumberRunner implements Runnable {
    private final NumberResource numberResource;
    private final Parity parity;

    NumberRunner(final NumberResource numberResource, final Parity parity) {
        this.numberResource = numberResource;
        this.parity = parity;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.printf("%s Thread::%d\n", parity.name(), numberResource.getNextNumber(parity));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Interrupted while trying to retrieve next number.");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

enum Parity {
    EVEN,
    ODD,
}
```